# Deploy portlets from a remote machine on Liferay 6.1.1 using plugins installation

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, marketplace

How can I deploy portlets from a remote machine on Liferay 6.1.1 using plugins installation.Till 6.0.1 it was possible,but now it redirects me to the marketplace and undeploying market place portlet,renders both plugins installation and plugins configuration in the same state,unable to deploy any new portlets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an over-eager way to introduce the marketplace. There is a fix - on marketplace - called [private plugin installer](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15474932). Install this and you can install new plugins from the UI again.